# Android first app, all activities visible in menu

Tags: android

I just created my first Android app, all works fine, but all of the activities are shown on my Android menu. What did I do wrong?

Screenshot: imgur.com/9CmXU 
I want to have one icon, directing to MainActivity, not all activities

```
    <!-- language-all: lang-html -->
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myApps.birthdaymeter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/my_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BirthdayMeter"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_birthday_meter" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutWindow"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about_window" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowResult"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_show_result" >
            <intent-filter>


  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my manifest, changing logo didn't help

Comment: Well how are we suppose to know if you don't show any code? and your question should explain more of what exactly are you doing.

Comment: Post your manifest file, please.

Comment: @user1590834 I have edited my question take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<intent-filter>` tag is used to describe the type of Intents that each Activity will respond to.  The `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` action says that this Activity is an entrance point for your Application (think the main method that a java program requires).  The `"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` category tells the OS to display the Activity in your list of Applications.  Adding the `DEFAULT` category is ok, but effectively the same as omitting the `<intent-filter>` tag completely (which I find to make for much cleaner and easier to read code).  You should only be using the `<intent-filter>` tag with these two actions and categories on the Activity that starts when a user opens your app.  If wanted an Activity within your application to be able to respond to some special intents, you would use the tag to define which it responds to.

Here's a link to the google dev pages to help you learn more about Intent Filters.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Here's the documentation for the `<intent-filter>` tag.  It's not the easiest to understand though.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

And here's the docs for the Manifest file and the Intent class.  Both of these are good for reference if you're not sure about which tags to use in your Manifest.  Good luck!

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

You phrased your question extremely generally, so I am not sure what to answer. It seems like you haven't called `nameOfActivity.this.finish()` when you launched another activity

Answer (score 0):

If you post your manifest file I can help a little more, but it looks to me like you have not declared your activities correctly.

It should be setup somewhat like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="Activity1"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Activity2"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Activity3"></activity>
</application>
```

Essentially, create an application declaration, and then include each activity within it.